# How ignore not annoted methods using OpenFeign SpringMvcContract

Tags: spring-boot, openfeign

I'm using swagger-codegen to genrate the interface for my Feign Client.

However the swagger-codegen generates these methods :

```
Optional<ObjectMapper> getObjectMapper();

Optional<HttpServletRequest> getRequest();
```

And when I run my application I receive this excpetion:

```
FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method getRequest not annotated with HTTP method type (ex. GET, POST)
```

I want to add to my FeignConfig something that tells to ignore the getObjectMapper(), getRequest() from my interface!

Is this possible ?

Comment: If I can say to my SpringMvcContract to ignore some methods, it will resolve my issue - I think!

Comment: Have you found a solution? Im facing the same problem. I have tried many many things autoconfiguring. I shouldn't be recreating a feign client in my  controllers that host the feign clients to make subsequent calls. It should be plug and play so to say, yet swagger keeps generating feign client apis with empty getObjectMapper and getRequest methods. Have you found a solution?

Comment: My solution was just to write another interface with the methods I want...

Comment: So then you are not generating openfeign clients with swagger no? You create them manualy. Is that so?

Comment: For this specific client no, i just write my own interface unfortunately! Just because the issue mentioned above!

Comment: Yes. It doesn't make sense. As I said, clients should be plug and play. I don't understand why the objectmapper and other methods are empty. We shouldn't be forced to use a Builder or new contract

Comment: Yes! I agree!, it should be able to ignore the not annotated methods!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue, I just added default for getObjectMapper(), getRequest().

```
@Override 
default Optional<ObjectMapper> getObjectMapper() {
    return Optional.empty();
}

@Override 
default Optional<HttpServletRequest> getRequest() {
    return Optional.empty();
}
```